# Isn't a Gem::Specification error after trying to install thumbshooter as a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

Every time I run rake or bundle I am now getting this error message:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/specifications/thumbshooter-0.1.5.gemspec] isn't a Gem::Specification (NilClass instead).
```

This started happening after I tried installing thumbshooter as a gem.

I tried to uninstall the gem, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. Also thumbshooter doesn't seem to be installed anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
rm $rvm_path/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/specifications/thumbshooter-0.1.5.gemspec
```